# Git internals: how does remote internally work

Tags: git, git-remote

Git remote is just a [Git custom references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References). How can I create a remote using only plumbing and porcelain commands without using `git remote add`?

Actually, I need a custom remote (let's call it `myremote`) similar to my current setup:

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/iterative/example-get-started (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/iterative/example-get-started (push)
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: It's written into `.git/config`. You can use `git config remote.myremote.url https://github.com/iterative/example-get-started`, or even `echo '[remote "myremote"]' >> .git/config; echo "url = https://github.com/iterative/example-get-started" >> .git/config`. Why do you not want `git remote add`?

Comment: I need my own "remotes" to store additional info per repository - with my own `remote add`. I'm basically "reinventing" remotes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here: you're mixing together *remotes*, like `origin`, and *remote-tracking names* (which Git calls *remote-tracking branch names* ).

A *remote* is just a short name under which several config values are stored:

- at the least, `remote.name.url`;
- usually, `remote.name.fetch`;
- optionally, `remote.name.pushurl` and various other settings.

Once these exist, you can run `git fetch name`, `git push name`, and so on.  You can also use the `git remote` command with its various sub-commands to update some of those config values, and (as `git remote update`) to run the equivalent of `git fetch`, for instance, to one or more remotes.  You can define remote *groups* for `git remote` to use when updating.

> How can I create a remote using only plumbing and porcelain commands without using `git remote add`?

The "without using `git remote add`" constraint is a bit silly, but:

```
git remote add myremote <url>
```

is shorthand for:

```
git config remote.myremote.url <url>
git config remote.myremote.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myremote/*'
```

except with additional error checking (e.g., making sure that `remote.myremote` does not already exist as a remote).